# Events only for updating projection

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

We're introducing event sourcing and refactoring to a rich domain model in a part of our application and we're a little bit confused about a part.

We have `Tank`s, which are the aggregate root and we receive `TankGauge` information on those `Thank`s every so often. Since the historical gauging information is not relevant for any business logic, the aggregate doesn't hold a collection of all the gauges, it only has a reference to the most recent gauge.

To display the historical gauges, we do have a projection set up.

Now we're getting the request: we want to update remarks on a historical gauge. The only relevancy this has is on the projection that holds the historical gauges. This causes a situation in which applying the `RemarkSetOnHistoricalGauge` event on the aggregate is basically a no-op and only the projection will be updated accordingly.

This works but it feels counter a bit counter-intuitive. Any suggestions on this approach?

Comment: Your solution seems appropriate to me.  An aggregate records events and changes in remarks certainly appear to be domain events.  The fact that it doesn't mutate any domain state shouldn't really matter since the same situation would arise with any classification of data.  Classification is really only for reporting on data but would need to be recorded, including the changes in reporting.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider whether you have two bounded contexts here:

- the tank gauging context: consuming `TankGauge` commands, validating that they make sense (if you're not, then there's not really a point to having the `Tank` aggregate) and emitting a `TankGaugeWas` (`TankLevelWas`?) event
- the tank history context: allowing remarks/annotations to be made regarding historical levels

Both of these have a concept of a tank, but not the same one.  The history context consumes events from the gauging context (those events become commands, implicitly "incorporate this event into your worldview", from the perspective of the history context).  They can have different aggregate logic: it might even be worth modeling a tank history aggregate as being time-windowed, e.g. that the tank tomorrow is not the same aggregate as the same tank today (this has the main benefit that you don't have to load the entire history of measures or scan through a history of snapshots).

This ability to actually cover the situation where different contexts are using a term to mean different things is one of the strengths of DDD (and the fact that the term takes on a different meaning is a very strong sign that there's a context boundary being crossed).

Comment: In CQRS terms, consider that the read-side being fed by the projection can itself also be a write-side which can take remarks.

Comment: We actually considered something like that but came to the conclusion that a gauge on its own cannot exist and is always part of a tank (come to think of it, this is mostly because of a certain perspective). Not just that it says something about that tank, but to calculate it, we also need properties of the tank itself and its contents.

Comment: Forget that I called it the tank gauging context, then, but rather the "tank in the now" context.

Comment: After a lengthy conversation with the team we have indeed come up with a design based on what you outlined here. It appeared that our aggregate Tank was way too big. A good additional reference here was Implementing Domain-Driven Design.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing events as they happen in the external world is orthogonal to using the events to re-hydrate an aggregate. The fact that the aggregate does not map an event today is just happenstance, which could change over time. But capturing the event is a necessity.

As an aside, raising events that have no immediate relevance to the Aggregate but are valuable for projections is normal.

I have a similar example from my past. Our `Identity` domain listened to events published in the `Email` subdomain to raise `EmailSent` and `EmailDelivered` events within itself against emails sent earlier to a user. These events can sometimes arrive out of sequence if the user continues to use the website. The aggregate does not hold attributes to represent this information, but such events helped cross-check signups and conversions.